# Child elements of link not overriding text-decoration when link is display flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a some trouble when link css display property is flex: child elements of link not overriding text-decoration property.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wu627vn3/

```
.test{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    color: red;
}

<a href="#" style="display: flex;">
    <div class="test">
        This isn't.
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        This isn't.
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `text-decoration` to anchor

```css
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<a href="#" style="display: flex;">
  <div class="test">
    This isn't.
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    This isn't.
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Yes. It's solution but I want to know a reson. Why? It's looks like bug.

Comment: @JonSnowKnowsNothing It is not a bug. By default, the anchor is inline while you have nested inline-block elements inside it. Hence the underline is not visible in this case. When you set display: flex, then the underline becomes visible.

Comment: @JonSnowKnowsNothing The underline that you're seeing is that of the anchor element, not the 'div's; `text-decoration` is not an inheritable property.

Comment: @KK
Ok! I understood! Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel
Ok! I understood! Thank you!